# Select Box option keep changing

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

```
<Select id="amount" onchange="document.formName.submit(); updateCost();">
   <option id="0" value = "0"> Select amount ... </option>
   <option id="1" value = "2000"> $2000 </option>
   <option id="2" value = "3000"> $3000 </option>
   <option id="3" value = "4000"> $4000 </option>
   <option id="4" value = "5000"> $5000 </option>
</Select>

<Select id="duration" onchange="document.formName.submit(); updateCost();">
   <option id="1" value="2 years"> 2 years </option>
   <option id="2" value="6 years"> 6 years </option>
   <option id="3" value="Lifetime"> Lifetime </option>
</Select>

function updateCost() {      
  var rate = 0;
  if(document.formName.plan[p].checked) {
    if(value('coverageUser').indexOf('Enrolled') > -1){
       rate = getRate();    
    }
    payCycle = 1;
    document.formName.cost.value = formatCurr((rate) * payCycle);
  }    
}
```

I have these two select boxes and when I choose an option from first, cost is getting updated correctly. But after selecting amount, I am supposed to select duration from second selectbox where default value is `2 years`. But when I change the value to `6 years`, cost is updated , but the select box option does not remain to `6 years`, but changes back to `2 years`. How do I keep the option I selected in second select box and also update the cost correctly?

Comment: Where's the updateCost() function?

Comment: If you're making the form submit whenever you change, then presumably the page is reloading and the select boxes are returning to default.

Comment: you can't fire some javascript after submitting a form, as the submit would cause a post-back and reload the page.

Comment: @j08691 - updateCost() function is in the same code, but it only changes the value of cost using the amount or duration one selected.

Comment: @JacobM - Even if I remove document.formName.submit(), it doesn't help as it doesn't show me the value of cost.

Comment: Again, we're going to need to see the updateCost() code... there's nothing really executing in the snippet you gave... also show the markup that is to receive the updated cost.

Comment: @grav3nimag3 - I added the code for updateCost() function.

Comment: there must be some more code that interferes with #duration

Comment: Can you post something on fiddle.com with the full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select boxes don't keep their state because of the submit you're doing at `onchange()`.
It will cause page reload on every change. Try remove it from both `select`'s.

Besides that, you're using `id` in a wrong way: you can't have the same `id` twice in a same page. Try something like this:

```
    <option value="1"> 2 years </option>
    <option value="2"> 6 years </option>
    <option value="3"> Lifetime </option>
```

Comment: I concur with tcurvelo on both points, though the duplicate ID shouldn't have any effect until you try to reference one of them with a script. Is there a particular reason you want to submit onchange()? If there is no avoidable server-side dependency during the selection phase of your form, you should be able to safely remove those submits.

Answer (score 1):

When you return the page after a form submit:

- Mark the user's selected options with the `selected` attribute:

  ```
  <select id="duration">
      <option value="2 years"> 2 years </option>
      <option value="6 years" selected> 6 years </option>
      <option value="Lifetime"> Lifetime </option>
  </select>
  ```
- Call `updateCost()` on page load:

  ```
  window.onload = updateCost;
  ```

  Or add it to your `window.onload` function if you already have one:

  ```
  window.onload = function() {
      ...
      updateCost();
  };
  ```